# How to use UTTypePlainText as a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project that used to support pre-iOS 15 versions but now only supports iOS 15+. Since the change, I received the following Xcode warning for the following line of code:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: NSData(data: data), typeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String)
```

> 'kUTTypePlainText' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UTTypePlainText instead.

Substituting `UTTypePlainText` in does not remedy the warning because it cannot find it in scope. The following also does not work:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: NSData(data: data), typeIdentifier: UTType.plainText)
```

I can't find any clear documentation on this type. I've imported `UniformTypeIdentifiers`, `CoreFoundation`, `CoreServices`, and `MobileCoreServices` to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After importing `UniformTypeIdentifiers` you can use `UTType.plainText` to get the needed `UTType`. Then use its `identifier` property to get the `String`.

So your line becomes:

```
let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: NSData(data: data), typeIdentifier: UTType.plainText.identifier)
```